# Group of checkbox and Other textbox with the same name attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Let's say I have a couple of checkbox selections:

```
<p class='question'>Reasons why it is down. Click as many as apply.</p>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down' value='Decrease in demand' required>Decrease in demand <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down' value='Expected Decrease in demand'>Expected Decrease in demand <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down' value='Technical difficulties in production'>Technical difficulties    in production <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down' value='Shortage in raw materials'>Shortage in raw materials <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="production-down" value='other' />Other
<input id='productionDownOther' name='other-production-down' type='text'/>
```

If I were to check the `other` checkbox. Should I give the `#productionDownOther` textbox the same name attribute as the checkboxes? Is that how it should be?

I'm planning to use the php method `implode` to add the selected values together and insert it into one column of database.

Please tell me if my plan is wrong, if yes/no tell me why. I'm kinda new in Web Development. Still looking forward to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you want to allow for multiple options? or only one checkbox is allowed at a time. If it is the first option, you will need to put `[]` at the end of each checkboxes name so `production-down` becomes `production-down[]`. This way, PHP will put all values into an array instead of overwriting the previous value with the next one. If you only want one option, change `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"`.

As for your **other** option, You could do something like this:

```
<?php

$other = null;
if (in_array('other', $_POST['production-down']) || $_POST['production-down'] == 'other') {
    $other = $_POST['other-production-down'];
}

// database stuff here
```

Please be aware that you should always sanitise data before database entry. Also, it would be wise to check if  the post values actually exist so PHP doesnt throw a notice.

Answer (score 0):

just make change of name attribute to array as:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Decrease in demand' required>Decrease in demand <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Expected Decrease in demand'>Expected Decrease in demand <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Technical difficulties in production'>Technical difficulties    in production <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Shortage in raw materials'>Shortage in raw materials <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="production-down[]" value='other' />Other
<input id='productionDownOther' name='other-production-down' type='text'/>
```

and to insert use `implode`

```
$check=$_POST['check'] //it is array of checkbox value
//convert in in string with comma seprated
$new_check=implode(",",$check);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use name as array for your purpose like this

```
<html> 
<head>  
<?php if(isset( $_POST['production-down'])) {
$name =  $_POST['production-down'];

foreach ($name as $color){
if($chk == "other" )
$chk=$_POST['production-down-name'];

echo $chk."<br />"; }  }?>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
   <p class='question'>Reasons why it is down. Click as many as apply.</p>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Decrease in demand' required>Decrease in demand <br>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Expected Decrease in demand'>Expected Decrease in demand <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Technical difficulties in production'>Technical difficulties    in production <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='production-down[]' value='Shortage in raw materials'>Shortage in raw materials <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="production-down[]" value='other' />Other
<input id='productionDownOther' name='production-down-name' type='text'/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>   
</body>
</html>
```